# How to find element in Selenium WebDriver if it is impossible to inspect

Tags: selenium

I am new to Selenium and recently got this question on the interview: 1.Open amazon.com 2. Type in to search box 'men shoes' 3.Click on the last displayed option. I found that I cannot inspect that drop-down where all options are displayed. How to find this web element with all the options?

Comment: Did you mean the options that comes as suggestions. Like `mens shoes without lace,
mens shoes sports`

Comment: yes, all that options

Comment: in inspector press Ctrl-F.  Search for "suggestions".  It'll get you part of the way there... you'll be able to then see (if you keep inspector open) a div with id of "suggestions" in a div with id of "nav-flyout-searchAjax" It takes content/template from <script type "text/html"> tags?

Comment: luckily it's only marked as "display: none" when focus is lost... so the content is still there.  Maybe a useful method is to search inspector for expected text in the suggestions list after it appears once.  You can then get to that part of the DOM in inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that. Below is code.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/")
driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox").send_keys("mens shoes")
opt = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'issDiv')]")
time.sleep(5)
for o in opt:
    print(o.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

[image: AmzSuggestions]

Comment: thanks, it works. But how did you find that element ? It disappears once I try to inspect it.

Comment: I can't see elements matching this locator there...

Comment: I just want to know the concept of finding this kind of elements. This code works, but what is the logic to find this 'dynamic drop down' element?

Comment: @Tatiana,@Prophet - Yes, I understand once we right click on suggestions, it disappears. But after several trial, I was able to get that inspect option.

Comment: I have uploaded a screen shot.